# In "The Peace War," what is meant by "tracer stench?"

Tags: the-peace-war

In [*The Peace War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1408) by Vernor Vinge:

> She slipped Quiller's in place and turned on the oxygen feed. She recognized the smell that still hung in her helmet: The tracer stench that tagged their landing fuel.

That smell from the tracer was inside the helmet? Why he says “the smell that still hung on her helmet”? The smell was there since when?  The smell got to the helmet after she turned on the oxygen feed?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley: Is there anything that Valorum can add to their answer for acceptance?

Comment: Mercaptan - http://www.safegas.org/about/about.html

Answer (score 8):

Parker and Quiller have just survived a crash; the fuel tanks of their craft have been breached, along with their hull, and fuel is mixing in the air that is entering the cabin.

The "tracer stench" is presumably like the mercaptan that is added to natural gas so that people are immediately aware when there is a gas leak.  Many fuels, especially those composed all or mostly of straight-chain hydrocarbons have little to no intrinsic smell.  (Even the "petrol" smell of automobile fuel is mostly due to the presence of small amounts of benzene compounds in the mix.)

The smell was present in the cabin of their craft because of the leaking fuel and the hull breach.  Even after Parker puts on her helmet, the flow of bottled oxygen will not immediately have flushed the tainted cabin air from her helmet, her hair and her respiratory system.  Note that Parker is not initially wearing her helmet and is breathing air directly from the cabin:

> She snapped the disk pack to her side and pulled down the light helmet with its ten-minute air supply.

---

As to why she only notes the smell of the tracer chemical *after* she has her helmet on, and is putting on Quiller's, there are a few possibilities.  The most probable explanation is only at *that* point does her brain have enough spare attention to consciously note it; up until that point she has been orienting herself after a crash, coping with a hull-breach situation and trying to ensure Quiller is safe.

An alternate explanation is that it is simply this point in her *narrative* that she mentions it.  During the events she may have noticed it immediately, and it may have been part of the reason she reacted to a hull breach, but we can tell from the way the scene is described that this is a recounting, rather than an in-the-moment description.

> Without thinking, she was following the hull-breach procedures that had been drilled into all of them so many times. **If she had thought about it** she might have left off the helmet - there were sounds of birds and wind-rustled trees - and she would have died.

You can't second-guess your own actions in real-time, and if this were being described as present action she would not yet have been aware that the helmet will be necessary to keep from dying in the fire that hasn't fully erupted.

Comment: But she recognizes the smell only after she puts her helmet?

Comment: She only _mentions_ it after she puts the helmet on. Since this is after-the-fact narration (based on the "if she had thought about it..." line) we don't know if she only chooses to mention it at this point, or if she only then _consciously_ noted it when she mentions it.

Comment: (There are also chemicals that have a strong smell at lower concentrations, but at a high enough concentration stop having a perceptible smell - with hydrogen sulphide this is *very* dangerous - so it's possible that only after she put her helmet on did the concentration of the tracer chemical drop low enough for her to smell it.)

Comment: Was she already using the helmet? The smell was on the cabin also on the helmet?

Comment: The smell was in the cabin; landing fuel from the crushed nose tanks mixing in the air and coming in through the breaches in the hull.  "She snapped the disk pack to her side and pulled down the light helmet with its ten-minute air supply."  So she wasn't wearing the helmet until _after_ the crash, and was breathing cabin air (containing traces of fuel) until she got her helmet's air supply turned on.  And then it would take some time to fully flush residual cabin air from her helmet, so the smell would linger.

Answer (score 6):

From context, it sounds like they add [mercaptan](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/what-exactly-is-mercaptan-8462250.html) (or some similar foul-smelling chemical agent) to the fuel oil to make it easier to detect leaks.

Note that your quote is wrong. The smell isn't **on** her helmet, it's ***in*** it.

> *She slipped Quiller's in place and turned on the oxygen feed. She
>   recognized the smell that still hung in her helmet: The tracer stench
>   that tagged their landing fuel.*